# java compiler options i.e. javac -d

Tags: java, javac

I'm compiling a program that has a package statement. 
e.g.

```
package APPC_LU62.Runtime ;
```

I also have a pre-existing directory structure that matches the package statement.

```
C:\APPC_LU62\Runtime
```

How do I keep the javac compiler from creating the same directory structure within the pre-existing one ? i.e.

```
C:\APPC_LU62\Runtime\APPC_LU62\Runtime
```

It seems to me the compiler ought to be "smart" enough to check first for an existing directory structure before creating one.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the compiler expects the source files and outputs the class files according to the package structure.

If you don't give any `-sourcepath` (or `-classpath` if no sourcepath is given) options, the source files are searched relative to the current directory. If a source path is given, the source files are searched relative to this path (in addition to any file directly specified on the command line).

Similarly, if you don't specify any `-d` options, the class files will be put into directories according to the package structure, relative to the current directory. If you give an `-d` option, the class files will be put relative to the directory given by the option. Non-existing directories will be created here.

Thus, if you want to create the output in the same directory tree as your source files are, the usual way to go would be to change into the root of this tree (`C:\` in your case), and from there call javac:

```
javac -classpath ... -sourcepath . APPC_LU62\Runtime\*.java
```

(or list only the java files you actually want to compile). Alternatively, you could add the `-d C:\` and `-sourcepath C:\` options, and then call the command from whereever you want:

```
javac -classpath ... -sourcepath C:\ -d C:\  C:\APPC_LU62\Runtime\*.java
```

The same is valid later for executing the classes with the `java` command: This also expects the classes in directories according to the package structure, with the root being a directory or jar file mentioned in the class path. Thus you will have to add `C:\` to the `-classpath` for your `java` call.

(By the way, I would not use the root of some drive as the root of the package hierarchy - better move everything one directory down.)

Answer (score 6):

Would have been better if you had actually posted your `javac` command and stated clearly where your sources are located, but here goes anyway: when you issue `javac -d somedir blahblah.java`, `javac` will create the appropriate directory structure (matching package name hierarchy) *starting at* directory `somedir`.

So in your case, you simply need to do:

```
javac -d c:\ your_files.java
```

Comment: Hi Mat, and thanks for the "heads-up" on accepting answers... I never knew that what the check mark is for... I'm not very good at understanding symbols... I work better with words.  However here's the contents of my options file that I pass to the java compiler:    
-g -verbose
-deprecation
-implicit:class 
-classpath C:\JVM\ibm_sdk60\;C:\JVM\CS_SNA_API_Client\;C:\JVM\CS_SNA_API_Client\CPICJAVA.JAR;C:\JVM\CS_SNA_API_Client\CPICJAVA.DLL 
-sourcepath C:\APPC_LU62\Runsrc

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a way to PREVENT the compiler from creating a new directory structure each time I run the compiler. How do I "tell" the compiler to use my existing directory structure. Thanks

Comment: @Guy: Another tip: Add such comments to the question, there is an edit link there.