# Does the javac command automatically create directories specified in the package declaration?

Tags: java, javac

I've always used an IDE when working with Java so my knowledge on the javac command isn't that great. I want to know this: Does java generate the directories where the .class files should be placed in as specified in the .java files package declarations? Let me clarify, say you have a simple .java file like this on your Desktop:

```
package com.deangrobler.test

public class Test {

    // ...

}
```

When running the following from your Desktop:

> javac Test.java

Will it then automatically go and create the com/deangrobler/test directories and place the Test.class file therein?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921042/java-compiler-options-i-e-javac-d

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html
See the option section.

-d directory

Set the destination directory for class files. The directory must already exist; javac will not create it. If a class is part of a package, javac puts the class file in a subdirectory reflecting the package name, creating directories as needed. For example, if you specify -d C:\myclasses and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass, then the class file is called C:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class.
If -d is not specified, javac puts each class files in the same directory as the source file from which it was generated.

Note: The directory specified by -d is not automatically added to your user class path.

Comment: I think that -d is to set the path of the generated .classes. If you don't expecify it, it will be './' but he's asking about the package's directories.

Comment: Mentioned in the last part --> If -d is not specified, javac puts each class files in the same directory as the source file from which it was generated.

Comment: Ah perfect! So I could just run 'javac -d . Test.java' from my desktop and it'll create the directories.

Comment: Java 9 onwards, `javac` creates the output directory if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

If we use below command , it will create package structure from current directory.

```
javac -d . YourClassName.java
```

If we want to put your class files and its packages some other folder, use below command.

```
javac -d "d:/java_eg/" YourClassName.java
```

it will create package directories and class files inside `java_eg` folder inside the `D` drive.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it then automatically go and create the com/deangrobler/test
>   directories and place the Test.class file therein?

**No.** Even if you can use `-d` to specify where you want to place your `class` file created after compilation but java won't create package structure for you.

So,Unless you specify the `-d` option the compiler places each class file in the same directory as the corresponding source file was located.

Even if you have specified package name but you hadn't created that structure don't expect that from `javac` all the things you have to do manually.

For Example:

```
javac -d C:/tempFolder MyProgram.java//Will place .class file in to C:/tempFolder
//Only if C:/tempFolder is available
```

---

```
com
|
|---deangrobler
        |
        |-------test
                  |
                  |---Test.class//Places class file here after compilation
                   //Default place
```