# what is meant by javac -d . classname.java

Tags: java, compilation

I encountered this while watching a video on java programming. I generally knew and even used javac classname.java to compile a java source code. hence, javac -d is kinda unknown to me. Can any one tell me its purpose?

```
javac -d . classname.java
```

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: What does `javac -help` tell you?

Comment: i didnt see that. . checking it out

Comment: @EJP no but I am going through it now as referred in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the compiler puts each class file in the same directory as its source file. You can specify a separate destination directory with the *-d* option.

More details - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJJJAJ

Answer (score 2):

It stands for the directory where the file class files are going to be created. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925168/2928459):

> If you give an `-d` option, the class files will be put relative to the
>   directory given by [this] option. Non-existing directories will be
>   created here.

Comment: @petehallw oops it was by mistake